# Better NLog logger name for F# modules and GetCurrentClassLogger()

Tags: f#, nlog

When I include `NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` at the top of my F# modules, the name of the logger looks something like `<StartupCode$NLogTest>.$Program`. I would have hoped for something like `NLogTest.TestModule`.

**How can I get a better logger name for my F# modules?**

Here is a complete example:

`Program.fs`

```
namespace NLogTest

type TestClass() =
    let logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
    member _.Run() =
        logger.Info("Inside my class")

module TestModule =
    let logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
    let Run() =
        logger.Info("Inside my module")

module Program =
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let Main _ =
        TestClass().Run()
        TestModule.Run()
        0
```

`NLogTest.fsproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="NLog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.13" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

`NLog.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

`Output`

```
2022-02-08 18:43:52.6678|INFO|NLogTest.TestClass|Inside my class
2022-02-08 18:43:52.6997|INFO|<StartupCode$NLogTest>.$Program|Inside my module
```

It's that last line that I would like to improve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are several options:

**Create the logger inside every module function**

```
module TestModule =
    let Run() =
        let logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
        logger.Info("Inside my module")
```

**Hard-code the logger name**

```
module TestModule =
    let logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("NLogTest.TestModule")
    let Run() =
        logger.Info("Inside my module")
```

**Use the `nameof` operator and make the module recursive**

*Does not include the namespace.*

```
module rec TestModule =
    let logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(nameof(TestModule))
    let Run() =
        logger.Info("Inside my module")
```

**Create a GetCurrentModuleLogger() extension**<sup>1</sup>

*Seems to work in lots of cases, but could probably be more robust.*

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module NLogExtensions =
    open NLog
    type LogManager with
        static member GetCurrentModuleLogger() =
            let moduleFullName = 
                System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(1, false)
                    .GetFrames().[0]
                    .GetMethod()
                    .DeclaringType
                    .FullName
            let moduleName = moduleFullName.Split("$") |> Seq.last
            LogManager.GetLogger(moduleName)
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Thanks to the [NLog.FSharp](https://github.com/Ravadre/NLog.FSharp/blob/master/NLog.FSharp/Logger.fs) library for pointing me in this general direction.</sup>